# Can I use OTG USB pendrive with Galaxy Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, usb-host-mode, usb-on-the-go

I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus. It is said to fully support OTG devices. However, I'm only able to use a mouse or keyboard through OTG USB cable. When I'm trying to connect my newly bought USB pendrive, the  phone doesn't detect it.

I have an USB pendrive with dual plug: standard USB + microUSB. I tried connecting it both through built-in microUSB and through standard USB via USB OTG cable. No effect on any attempt.

What am I missing? Is the pendrive broken or doesn't the Samsung Galaxy Nexus support external pendrives and has only keyboard/mouse OTG support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it works. You need to root and install the [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount) app. [Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/galaxy-nexus-otg-support-t1518211).

Comment: I forgot to add (to my question) that, I'm asking for an answer without need of root, but you were faster! :] Thank you...

Comment: One side question: Is there any way to determine, approximately how many devices with Android will require root to use USB OTG pendrive? I only need general answer. Is this something normal (70-90% devices requires this) or something unique (10-30% devices requires this or even Galaxy Nexus is a lonely exception).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can mount it in terminal:

```
mkdir /data/local/usbstick && mount - t ext4 /dev/block/sda1 /data/local/usbstick
```

Then you can execute.

Comment: Again, I was rather looking for _an everyday newbie user_ solution. Not the one, that requires rooting or playing with terminal. So, while I'm grateful for your answers, the real answer to _my_ question is (at least for me): "You can't".